# A list of path to a dictionnary

Tags: python, dictionary, path

I am trying to populate a python dict from a list of paths (the purpose is to create a ttk.treview) :

```
paths = ["\\hihi", "\\hihi\\hoho\\huhu", "\\hihi\\hoho\\haha", "\\haha", "\\huhu"]
```

and I want to create this dictionnary (json serialized here) :

```
{
   "haha": {},
   "hihi": {
       "hoho": {
           "huhu": 0
       },
       "huhu": {
           "haha": 0
       }
   },
   "huhu": {}
}
```

What is the best way to do this? I tried with a for loop (recursive loop?), with a dict comprehension and with dpath but I have no valid result.

The biginning of my code :

```
split = paths.split("\\")
del split[0]
dict = {}
?
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use `defaultdict` for this:

```
def make_empty_default_dict():
    return defaultdict(make_empty_default_dict)
```

Define how you add a path:

```
def add_path(pth, dct):
    if pth:
       subdict = dct[pth[0]]
       return add_path(pth[1:], subdict)
    else:
       return dct
```

Then populate your default dict with keys:

```
d = make_empty_default_dict()
for path in paths:
  d = add_path(path.split("\\"), d)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work for me. I searched for Defaultdict and iI found the answer, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative to the recursive solution. For each path:

- put a cursor at the root of the target dict
- search sequence: move the cursor forth until you find a 0 or a missing part of the path
- build sequence: add an empty dict and move the cursor on that dict until you hit the last part.
- the last part needs a special handling for the 0.

Here's the code:

```
def build_paths(paths, d={}):
    for path in paths:
        parts = path.split("\\")[1:] # remove the part before \

        cursor = d
        search = True
        for part in parts[:-1]:
            if search:
                if part not in cursor or not cursor[part]: # not found or 0
                    cursor[part] = {} # set a new dict
                    search = False
            else:
                cursor[part] = {}
            cursor = cursor[part] # advance one level deeper in the dict
        cursor[parts[-1]] = 0 # close with a 0

    return d
```

It's faster than the recursive vesion of @xtofl, but not that fast. With `timeit`:

```
iterative: 6.169872568580601
recursive: 17.209112331781498
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
paths = ["\\hihi", "\\hihi\\hoho\\huhu", "\\hihi\\hoho\\haha", "\\haha", "\\huhu"]
new_paths = [list(filter(None, i.split('\\'))) for i in paths]
def update_output(f):
  def wrapper(_d):
    result = f(_d)
    final = lambda x, level = 0:{a:{} if not level and not b else b if not b else final(b, level+1) for a, b in x.items()}
    return final(result)
  return wrapper
@update_output
def full_directory(data):
  def files(d):
    return {a:(lambda x:0 if len(x) == 1 else files([i[1:] for i in filter(lambda y:len(y) != 1 or y[0] != a, x)]))(list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
  return files(data)

print(full_directory(new_paths))
```

Output:

```
{'haha': {}, 'hihi': {'hoho': {'haha': 0, 'huhu': 0}}, 'huhu': {}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this : http://connor-johnson.com/2015/02/28/generate-a-tree-structure-in-python/

It works very well! So the code :

```
def add(t, path):
   for node in path:
       t = t[node]

Tree = lambda: defaultdict(Tree)
t = Tree()

paths = ["\\hihi", "\\hihi\\hoho\\huhu", "\\hihi\\hoho\\haha", "\\haha", "\\huhu"] 

for path in paths:
   split = path.split("\\")
   del split[0]

   for elt in split:
       add(t, split)


dicts = lambda t: { k:dicts(t[k]) for k in t }

print(json.dumps(dicts(t), indent=4))
```